# Show position on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

My goal is to show a given position or location on a map (e.g. GoogleMaps).

I know there is the Geolocation in HTML5, but this shows just the current position of a user.

I thought about an iframe of google maps, and then pass the given position with jQuery to the search box of the iframe.

Is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: the web is full of examples how to pass coordinates to maps as markers. WHat makes your case any different? You haven't identified a real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the official **[Google Maps API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)**.

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
```

Comment: is it also possible to give as position e.g. an country, area, town, village or street?

Comment: @Smeaven at the end, a marker needs a defined position, you can use a web service from the google maps api in order to receive the coordinates for a specific town, country or villagre, yes ;)

Comment: I will take a look at this API and will come back, if there are any problems ;) thx.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to get the position when you click on the map

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    positionClicked = event.latLng();
});
```